# How to retrieve the currently logged in user with Backand

Tags: ionic-framework, backand

I am using the [Backand](https://www.backand.com) BaaS for my Ionic app. I am trying to retrieve the currently logged in user.

At the moment I am setting a $rootScope variable upon the login event with the signed in user.

Is there an easier way to do this process without having to programatically set my own 'loggedInUser' variable ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you logged in,
you can get user details with two methods.

```
 Backand.getUsername()
 Backand.getUserDetails()
```

You have to add 'Backand' service to your controller.

```
app.controller('ExampleCtrl', function(Backand){
     console.log(Backand.getUsername());
}
```

If user is not logged in, methods will return null.

Comment: Thank you @Ygalbel for this. I searched Backand Docs for this but couldn't find it prior to posting the thread. Are you able to direct me to documentation, if any ?

Comment: That's can be found [here](http://docs.backand.com/en/latest/apidocs/security/#sso-single-sign-on)  and in sdk part with more details [here](http://docs.backand.com/en/latest/getting_started/sdk/#usage)

Comment: The second link don't work, just search "getUserDetails" in search tab in help pages, and you will find it.